# How to run a large base64 encoded file via powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, base64

I have a powershell.ps1 script that I performed base64 encoding upon as below

```
$Base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('c:\path\to\powershell.ps1'));
```

Now I have stored this output to base64.txt file.

I tried to launch this script as below via CMD,

```
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand (Base64String)
```

But I ended up in the below error

```
Cannot process the command because the value specified with -EncodedCommand is not properly encoded. The value must be Base64 encoded.
```

I realized that the CMD is not taking the entire (Base64String). The full length of my (Base64String) is 11,133 characters. But CMD is accepting only 8160 characters.

Is there any way or workaround to run this base64 encoding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about redirection. `<`.

Comment: What purpose could this serve? Maybe there's a better way to accomplish it than encoding your whole script.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: If you follow your process and encode a smaller script file, does it work?

Comment: PowerShell requires the Base64 encoding to be based on UTF-16LE code units, not raw bytes. As for the length limit: instead of Base64 encoding, save the code to a script file (`*.ps1`) and execute with `powershell -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file script.ps1`

Comment: I have a script that has some sensitive information. In order to hide that,I need to convert this file to non readable format. Base64 encoding this file and using that encoded string to perform runs seemed to be an option here. But I’ve run into this.

Comment: Convert the sensitive information and store it and just load it in the script. But it's just security by obscurity. Better to find an actual solution that would protect your sensitive information.

Comment: @KahLeon not a good idea! Base64 encoding doesn't give you any security

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (`myscript.ps1` contains the base64 encoded command):

```
powershell -encodedcommand (Get-Content 'myscript.ps1' -Raw)
```

Which is very similar to what you would do in Bash:

```sh
$ powershell -encodedcommand `cat myscript.ps1`
```

**Obs:** Addressing some comments, this is sometimes indeed needed. My particular use case was to do a reverse shell while dodging an AV on a windows machine that was detecting my plaintext shell code.